# Ember.js Form Instant Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

After I placed the action inside the form tag (`<form {{action 'registerAccount'}}>`) I observed that the form is always submitted if the current input field looses focus.

If it is intended behaviour, how can I avoid this?

```
App.AccountRegisterController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    title: 'Registrieren',
    content: [],

    actions: {
        registerAccount: function () {
            var newAccount = this.get('store').createRecord('account', {
                email: this.get('email'),
                password: this.get('password'),
                isNewsletterSubscribed: this.get('isNewsletterSubscribed')
            });
            newAccount.save();
        }
    }
});
```

[image]

**Edit**:

My bad. Replace the previously mentioned action helper with this:

```
<form {{action 'registerAccount' on='submit'}}>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding `<form {{action 'registerAccount'}}>` , the `registerAccount` function will be called for every click inside your form e.g. when clicking inside the input fields to enter text.

By specifying the DOM event type `submit` by using the `on` property, the `registerAccount` function should be called for click events of type submit, meaning only for input of `type=submit` or `button` elements which are of `type=submit` by default.

It will assist if you can please post your handlebars template of `AccountRegisterView`.

I would suggest to place your `{{action}}` helper inside your button element i.e.

```
<button {{action 'registerAccount'}}>submit form</button>
```

Then your form submition will only take place when you click the button.

Unless it is something else you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

My bad. Replace the previously mentioned action helper with this:

```
<form {{action 'registerAccount' on='submit'}}>
```

Comment: you can edit your original post, instead of providing changes in the answers

Comment: This is the solution. Therefore I submitted it as answer. Isn't this correct?